# How do I check that a map element on a page can be zoomed in and out

Tags: python, robotframework

I am testing an web app which has a map element. The default is like this :

[image]

The related html code

```
  <div class="leaflet-proxy leaflet-zoom-animated" style="transform: translate3d(312px, 221px, 0px) scale(1);"></div>
```

Now if I click on the "+" button, The zoom level changes and the html code changes to :

```
<div class="leaflet-proxy leaflet-zoom-animated" style="transform: translate3d(624px, 442px, 0px) scale(2);"></div>
```

I need to find a way to verify that the zoom level actually changed when I clicked the Zoom in / Zoom Out buttons using Robot Framework or Python.

Comment: In what technical way would that check happen. By comparing the `style` attribute for a change in values or visually?

Comment: Hi, By comparing the style attribute can be sufficient. I am looking for that solution. But if the visual inspection can be automated, that will be great.

Comment: As I'm not in a position to test this myself I'm adding it as a comment. To me it seems like [Get Element Attribute](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute) would do the trick. This gives you the textual value that you then can compare. Comparing visually is possible, but is more complex. If you want to investigate it then [ImageHorizonLibrary](https://github.com/eficode/robotframework-imagehorizonlibrary) and [SikuliLibrary](https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary#readme) are the ones to look at.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will test it soon